# Loop (v-for) doesn't work with keen-slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops, vuejs3, slider

I'm using https://keen-slider.io and I'm trying to loop through the slides, each of which has a `<ItemCard/>` component. However, instead of displaying all of the slides with `<ItemCard/>`, it only displays one slide with all of the `<ItemCard/>` and it looks terrible.

```
<template>
        <div class="keen-slider" ref="container">
            <div
                class="keen-slider__slide"
                v-for="recipe in storeRecipe.data"
                :key="recipe.id">
                <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
<script setup>
import { useKeenSlider } from 'keen-slider/vue';
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useStoreRecipe } from '@/store/storeRecipe';

import ItemCard from '@/component/ItemCard.vue';

const storeRecipe = useStoreRecipe();

const [container] = useKeenSlider({
    loop: true,
    spacing: 40,
    slidesPerView: 3,
});

onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadRecipes();
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import url('keen-slider/keen-slider.css');
</style>
```

I also tried to add a second parameter `index` to `v-for` and then dynamically add a class `:class="'number-slide' + (index + 1)"`, but it also didn't work:

```
<template>
    <div class="keen-slider" ref="container">
        <div
            class="keen-slider__slide"
            :class="'number-slide' + (index + 1)"
            v-for="(recipe, index) in storeRecipe.data"
            :key="recipe.id">
            <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipe.pending" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: It obviously doesn't support tracking container contents, especially since it's not native vue lib and not aware of vue lifecycle. Considering that init time is fixed https://github.com/rcbyr/keen-slider/blob/master/src/vue.ts#L31 , try to update it when slides are ready in dom, like nextTick(() => slider.value.update())

Comment: keen-slider renders before Recipe is loaded so now slider = undefine. I think you should add `<div v-if="storeRecipe.data.lenght" class="keen-slider" ref="container">`  to check Recipe list before rendering keen-slider

Comment: @DinhTX didn't work.

Comment: @EstusFlask that becomes too difficult. I was looking for a slider that works well with Vue 3 and keen-slider's documentation says that it works with it. However, adding too much code makes this package meaningless (it's easier to write my own slider). If there's a simple solution without adding too much code, please let me know.

Comment: @Michael You picked the one that is not implemented in Vue, just has a wrapper. At this point you could just use any vanilla js library and integrate it with vue lifecycle, which is a common and reasonable thing, you aren't limited to vue 3 ecosystem, which is lacking. You'd need the amount of code that you could see in a linked wrapper, it's like several lines without TS specific things. Just add nextTick inside onMounted to that im[lementation to fix v-for, and that's it. I don't have one at hand, primevue has carousel but I'm not sure it's worth adding the whole lib for a single component

Comment: when I add nextTick I get ReferenceError: slider is not defined. Where did you find 'slider' in my code?